# Mysql query to get unique email-Id based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

TABLE :-

```
|    emailId     |   status   |
| --------       |  --------  |
| aa@gmail.com   | reject     |
| aa@gmail.com   | complete   |
| aa@gmail.com   | progress   |
| bb@gmail.com   | complete   |
| bb@gmail.com   | progress   |
| cc@gmail.com   | progress   |
| cc@gmail.com   | reject     |
| dd@gmail.com   | progress   |
| dd@gmail.com   | complete   |
| ee@gmail.com   | reject     |
| ff@gmail.com   | progress   |
```

Have more rows like this

Expecting result :-

```
|    emailId     |   status   |
| --------       |  --------  |
| aa@gmail.com   | complete   |
| bb@gmail.com   | complete   |
| cc@gmail.com   | progress   |
| dd@gmail.com   | complete   |
| ee@gmail.com   | reject     |
| ff@gmail.com   | progress   |
```

result should be unique email-id with status as follows - complete, progress, reject.

Answer (score 2):

Use `group by` and `min`:

```sql
select emailId, min(status)
from my_table
group by emailId
```

If your actual data doesn't lineup that perfectly, you'll need to use inner query converting status to integer values and selecting min/max, and outer query converting those integer values back.